# How can i disable whole jsp page while loading gif image is display on page submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

Friends

I am working on the Dynamic Web project.
I am creating JSP & Servalet Pages in my project

I am load a gif image at the time of the page submit
at that time i need to disable whole jsp page

Please anyone has an idea so please suggest me.

Answer (score 1):

Try [BlockUI plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/block/#demos) for jQuery.

Comment: This looks really good..